# Android sdkmanager not found and required files installed

Tags: flutter

i am getting this error 'Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.' when i run this 'flutter doctor --android-licenses'  and i have installed both andriod sdk command-line tools latest one and android sdk tools(obsolete) can anyone help me with this error

[image: this is the error]

[image: i have installed all which required]

pls help me with the installation

Comment: can you create emulator device?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.